# Interpolation Attack

Tags: cryptanalysis

The example of two round iterated cipher(each round is cubic function) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_attack#Example) shows polynomial after two rounds with 9 terms.

[image]

however if we find the polynomial for two rounds, it has 22 terms

[image]

one clue i have is, the difference in number of terms may be because of underlying mathematics difference, (use of finite field in case of 9 terms, so similar terms getting cancelled out instead of being add up)

and is there some formula to just find the number of terms in expansion, like explain [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171229130357/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/68607.html)

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the cryptosystem you have.

Comment: its just an example cipher with cubic round function

Comment: What characteristic is the field?

Comment: for example of wikipedia, it is not mention there, so can you tel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the first equation one has $(x+k_1)^3 = (x^2+k_1^2)(x+k_1)$, i.e., $(x+k_1)^2 = x^2+k_1^2$ I'd conclude that the equation is over characteristic $2$.

This explains why all the terms with even coefficients are missing and why all odd coefficients are replaced by $1$.

The only remaining mystery is what happened to $3k_1^6k_2$ rsp. $k_1^6k_2$. Typo?

Comment: The answer could have been typed without the comment, "or that the author should go back to middle school ;-))."

because you should have read about this cancellation in my question too :p

"the difference in number of terms may be because of underlying mathematics difference, (use of finite field in case of 9 terms, so similar terms getting cancelled out instead of being add up)"

Comment: "author" didn't refer to you. You made clear that you just copied the equations [assuming you didn't ask about what you added yourself to the wikipedia]. Anyway, it's clear by the first equation that the equation are in characteristic $2$ (or wrong) *and* that one term was forgotten. For the last sentence of your answer, I'd recommend to ask it on math.stackexchange.com (for characteristic $2$ specific, as odd $p$ might give another answer).

Comment: answer accepted :) thanks for suggestion about last line, going to post it there too :)